# In python, why do I get an error message of " unhashable type:'list'" when doing list(set(listB)-set(listA))?

Tags: python, list, set-difference

I have `listA=[[0,1,2]]`, and `listB=[[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,2,3]]`, and want to obtain elements that are in listB but not in listA, i.e., my desired output is listC=[[0,1,3],[0,2,3]].

I already got listC using list comprehension:

```
listA=[[0,1,2]]
listB=[[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,2,3]]
listC=[b for b in listB if b not in listA]
```

But if I want to do it in another way, i.e., using setdifference in the following code, I got the error message unhashable type:'list'.

```
 listA=[[0,1,2]]
listB=[[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,2,3]]
listC=list(set(listB)-set(listA))
```

Why does this error pop up? And how it could be fixed? Thanks!

Comment: In general, if you have some complex expression that causes an exception, the first thing you should do is try to figure out *which part of the expression* is causing the problem. Here, the problem occurs because of `set(listB)` and `set(listA)`. Each *element of* these lists is itself a list, which cannot be put into a set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sets require to **hash** the objects, and **lists are not hashable** (as they are mutable).

Thus you need to convert to tuple and back to list:

```
listA=[[0,1,2]]
listB=[[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,2,3]]
listC=list(map(list,set(map(tuple,listB))-set(map(tuple,listA))))
listC
```

output: `[[0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3]]`

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem.